# PHP or jquery code to add an object photo to another object photo?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Let`s say I have a car in a photo. It is a stock car.

I have some upgrade options:

-Tuning bumper
-Tuning wheels
-Nitro
-Body paint red
-...

It is possible by code (PHP or a Jquery library) to add to the stock car photo some elements I select from the list? Let`s say I choose body paint red. The car in the photo should change to red or if I select tuning wheels, only the wheels to change.

Like in [HERE](http://www.mercedes-benz.ro/content/romania/mpc/mpc_romania_website/rong/home_mpc/passengercars/home/new_cars/models/b-class/w246/configurator/configurator_w246.html#/p3503).

Comment: This question should be rejected as is.  It is too generic as you do not provide specifics about what you have already done and what problem you are having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use images over images to "modify" original stock car photo. Let's say your photos are 400x400, you could show photos one over another like this:

- Car stock photo
- Tuning wheels (fits the position of the car wheels in the previous photo and have transparent background)
- Body painted red (a photo of only the body of the car, but painted red and transparent background)

You can compose the photos in one using Canvas (for Javascript) or using the GD Library (for PHP).